# Can two grid-columns have reverse auto-rows order in a flexible grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid with two columns and two auto-rows of different sizes (3fr 6fr) repeating. Does anyone any idea how could I change the order of the rows in the second column of the grid (6fr 3fr)? So this has to be flexible, no matter how many items I put in the grid-container, the row order of the left column has to be 3fr 6fr, and the right 6fr 3fr (so grid-area, grid-column, order may not be appropriate here). Thank you in advance for your help...

Code:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  
<div class="grid-item">1</div>
<div class="grid-item">2</div>
<div class="grid-item">3</div>
<div class="grid-item">4</div>
<div class="grid-item">5</div>
<div class="grid-item">6</div>
<div class="grid-item">7</div>
<div class="grid-item">8</div>
<div class="grid-item">9</div>
<div class="grid-item">10</div>
<div class="grid-item">11</div>
<div class="grid-item">12</div>

</div>



.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 3fr 6fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

Codepen:

https://codepen.io/illestoth84/pen/LYywZgP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with **just** 3fr rows then use an nth-child formula to tell which items to `span 2` rows.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 3fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container :nth-child(4n-2),
.grid-container :nth-child(4n-1) {
  grid-row: span 2
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">

  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
  <div class="grid-item">10</div>
  <div class="grid-item">11</div>
  <div class="grid-item">12</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea what would be the solution with 4 columns? So:


.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 3fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}